# Using ag grid as nuxt component

Tags: nuxt.js, ag-grid

I would like to use Ag-grid as a component, then I would like to call it from many pages.
The component should fetch columns and data from the parent page.

Since I've been struggling a lot with this problem I would appreciate a simple example very much.
It seems that I always get some kind of timing problem between the page and my component.

If possible I would like to create the page with an empty grid and then load the data. But not sure if that is possible.

Thanks in advance
Håkan

My page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <aomGrid
      pagePath="/stock/"
      :fields="gridHeader.fields"
      :data="rowData"
    ></aomGrid>
  </div>
</template>
```

My component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ag-grid-vue
      class="ag-theme-fresh grid"
      :gridOptions="gridOptions"
      :rowDataChanged="onRowDataChanged"
      :rowData="gridData"
    >
    </ag-grid-vue>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      gridOptions: null,
      gridData: null,
    };
  },
  props: {
    fields: {
      type: Array
    },
    gridData: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  components: {
    AgGridVue
  },
    onRowDataChanged() {
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      });
    },
    created() {
      this.gridOptions = {};
      this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.fields;
    },
    beforeMount () {
     this.gridOptions.api.setRowData = this.gridData;
    }
  }
};
```